# Unable to launch the MAUI app after adding Entitlement.plist

Tags: ios, xamarin, maui

We are migrating our Xamarin forms project to MAUI with Entitlements.plist which was used in our forms project. Out app is not starting with Entitlements.plist after switching to MAUI. However, the app is launching in the device if Entitlements.plist is removed from both the project and the folder location. When we attempt to start the app with plist, the following error is returned.

xcrun simctl launch --stdout=/dev/ttys001 --stderr=/dev/ttys002 --terminate-running-process E89153ED-B3A1-46A1-BEA8-C59213F35BB2 com.sample.application -monodevelop-port 10000
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=3):
Application launch for 'com.sample.application' did not return a valid pid nor a launch error.
No such process
error HE0042: Could not launch the app 'com.sample.application' on the device 'Device Model': simctl returned exit code 3

The plist we use in our program is shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.microsoft.adalcache</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Is this required?

Comment: Did you follow the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/ios/entitlements) on this? Did you set up the provisioning profiles with the required entitlements/capabilities?

Comment: @H.A.H. Yes, it's necessary since we're utilizing MSAL/ADAL for authentication.

Comment: @Julian The entitlement plist file was incorporated before the MAUI migration, and there were no complications.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new capability to the app made publish profile on Apple Developer portal invalid.

Go to your Apple Developer Account, go to "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" and check if the profile that you are using is still active.

If not, click on the profile, review the information, save, and it should be active again.